# How is the minimum reputation for SO mod election candidates calculated?

Tags: discussion, nominations

When I tried to nominate myself for Stack Overflow moderator in the recent election, I received this message:

> You must have 6802 reputation to nominate yourself as a candidate in this election.

After some time passed, I checked again, and got a different message. The new one said:

> You must have 8092 reputation to nominate yourself as a candidate in this election.

On what basis were these reputations calculated? Were they the averages of the then-current nominees' reputations? The lowest value from among the then-current nominees' reputations?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to [the election blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/trilogy-2011-elections-begin/), the minimum rep for mod nominees is 3000 on Stack Overflow and 2000 on the other sites. However, only the 30 highest-rep nominees proceed to the primary election.

I suppose that since there are already 30 nominees, the system only allows you to nominate yourself if you have at least as much reputation as the lowest-rep user of the top 30, which was 8092 at your second check.

Comment: Hmmm, so that means the lower reputation people must file their nominations as soon as nomination process start or they will lose opportunity of nominating themselves.

Comment: @Sachin: I don't think it will make a difference. Even if you get your nomination in before there are 30 nominees, you won't get into the primary anyway if there are 30 other nominees with higher reputation, so all you've gained is a couple of hours of being listed on the nominees page (I assume once you're not in the top 30 anymore, you will no longer appear on the page).

Comment: @sepp2k - haha... ok.. Now I understand. Ok cool, thanks. Got it.

Comment: @Sachin Shanbhag: Remember that people may un-nominate themselves at any point. So if a lot of people decide to un-nominate themselves the actual limit may go down again (thus maybe the system needs to be changed so people with low scores do not need to check hourly for a mass desertion).

Comment: @Martin York - Hmm, true. I do agree with the system since there has to be someway of cutting down number of nominees since the list would be very huge anyway. Thanks for the valuable info. :)

Comment: What this means is if you don't have a VERY high rep, do yo wish to risk the time of putting your self forward, when a user with more rep may come alone later?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is still in effect, but I feel you should be able to nominate yourself regardless of if you meet the reputation requirement. After all, if you have 9999, and the lowest is 10000, it's very possible you will put yourself in the eligible stage before going to the primary.

That is to say the cut of who is going to the primary should only occur on the transition from nomination to primary, not before.

Comment: I have not been following up the 2011 moderator elections. However, the above question was asked during 2010 moderator elections. So I am not sure about recent changes.