# [10347] You must have more than 10347 reputation to nominate yourself as a candidate in this election

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, moderation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is the Minimal reputation for Moderator election on Stack Overflow calculated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75428/how-is-the-minimal-reputation-for-moderator-election-on-stack-overflow-calculated)

> In the nomination phase, any community member in good standing with more than **10347** reputation may nominate themselves to be a community moderator.

How has this been decided? Was it something like "42"?

https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools says:

> Reputation Required 10000

Bug? Corruption?

Comment: My guess is that this is because they are only allowing 30 total nominations. And there are already 30 nominations with reputation higher than 10347.

Comment: There is a minimal reputation, as explained in [How is the Minimal reputation for Moderator election on Stack Overflow calculated?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75428/how-is-the-minimal-reputation-for-moderator-election-on-stack-overflow-calculated). Only the top 30 nominees can be considered, so once 30 nominations are up it's only possible to self-nominate with at least as much reputation as the lowest one.

Comment: That must really feel like a slap in the face if you have *exactly* 10347 reputation.

Comment: Moderator Tools =/= Community Moderator

Comment: It changes dynamically. It is the lowest reputation score of the top 30 nominees. (providing they all have a minimum reputation of 3000 - which is the minimum reputation requirement for stack overflow nominations)